# Compare multiple image side by side

Tags: image, compare, diff, beyondcompare, winmerge

I know there are quite some good image comparing tools,

Beyond Compare can compare two images,
WinMerge can compare up to three images,
FastStone Image Viewer and XnViewMP can compare up to four images side by side.

But, if I got more than four images to compare side by side
(with synchronized zoom and pan, no need to highlight or blink the difference)

Is there some tool capable of doing this?

Answer (score 2):

I found nomacs has a Viewer Synchronization feature

Features | nomacs | Image Lounge
https://nomacs.org/features/

Just tried, work great and can Synchronize as many instances of the picture viewer as you want.

Comment: I'm curious to have an update 2 years later if you're still using it ?

Comment: Here is the update:
Releases · nomacs/nomacs
https://github.com/nomacs/nomacs/releases

Latest version now (2023-12-27) is 3.17.2289 Beta released Oct 4 2023.

Answer (score 0):

**Butterfly Viewer** can view multiple images side by side with synchronized panning and zooming. Simply drag and drop image files into it and it'll auto-arrange them in a grid, column, or row.

I'm the creator, and I released to the public on [GitHub](https://github.com/olive-groves/butterfly_viewer) a couple months ago.

You can [install it on Windows](https://olive-groves.github.io/butterfly_viewer/butterfly_viewer.html#windows-executable), run it as a [package for MacOS (beta)](https://olive-groves.github.io/butterfly_viewer/butterfly_viewer.html#macos-app), or run it directly on its Python source code.

Synced pan and zoom in a row:
[image: Animation of drag-and-drop with synchronized zoom and pan]

Independent pan and zoom in a grid:
[image: Image of six photos individually panned and zoomed]